# Setting up BART in a Solaris non-global zone (aka Solaris Zone)

Tags: security, solaris, containers

So my question is about running BART (The Solaris Basic Audit Reporting Tool) inside of a Solaris non-global zone. I'm confused on this subject due to I have been reading a lot of conflicting views, the man page says this:

*The root file system of any non-global zones must not be referenced with the -R option. Doing so might damage the global zone's file system, might compromise the security of the global zone, and might damage the non-global zone's file system*

So after researching this topic I have seen a lot of answer's that seem to go back and forth. People have said to run it in the global zone, some people have said to zlogin to the non-global zone and run it there.

So my question is, I have a bunch of Solaris non-global zones that I want to have BART check. Is it okay to ssh or zlogin to the non-global zone and run BART? What is the safest way to have BART check the "/" (aka root) directory and up of my non-global zones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After researching this some more and doing some testing, I have concluded that it's fine to run tools like BART inside of a non-global zone. However, tools like BART should not be run from the global zone to access non-global zones. Mostly this creates a possible security risk for malicious non-global admins that can point /zones//etc/passwd to /etc/passwd on the global.

So in short as long as you run BART inside of the non-global zone you should be fine, just dont have it run on the global zone and access the non-global zones.